# Nav also moves when applying margin top in TailWind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

When I try to apply margin-top to a container, the container moves, but so does the nav bar, do you guys know what can I do? I am using TailwindCSS, please check the images:

First Image
[image]

Second Image

[image]

```
<header>
  <nav class="w-full bg-white fixed flex border-b-2 border-opacity-50 z-10">
    <a class="" href="#home">
      <img class="mx-48 p-2 w-24" src="assets/logo/dfnr.png" alt="Diefonro logo" />
    </a>

    <ul class="nav-list flex text-gray-500 relative left-40 font-bold mt-1">
      <li class="p-3 mx-2 hover:text-gray-800">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="p-3 mx-1 hover:text-gray-800">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="p-3 mx-2 hover:text-gray-800">
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="p-3 mx-2 hover:text-gray-800">
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="p-3 mx-2 hover:text-gray-800">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container mt-16 mx-auto bg-gray-700" id="home">
    <p class="text-3xl">Hi! This is</p>
    <h1 class="title gradient-title">DIEFONRO</h1>
    <p class="pos-text">Junior Front-End Developer</p>
    <a href="#contact"><button class="hire">HIRE ME</button></a>
    <a href="assets/files/Diefonro's CV.pdf" download="Diefonro's CV"><button class="get-cv">GET CV</button></a>
    <img src="assets/img/Diefonro.png" alt="diefonro's ilustration" class="main-img" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: try removing "fixed" class from <nav> And "mt-16" from ".container"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding `top-0` to the `<nav>` will fulfill your wish.

Comment: Literally solved it, thank you so much!